# flake8 and vscode: disable linebreak after each argument in function call

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint, pep8, flake8

Currently flake8 formats my code like this:

```
def foo_bar_maybe_long_name(
    argument1,
    argument2,
    another_argument,
    and_a_last_one,
):
```

which IMO makes the code long and difficult to read.
I would like somehting like this, which is pep8 compliant I think:

```
def foo_bar_maybe_long_name(
    argument1, argument2, another_argument,
    and_a_last_one):
```

I have the same issue with other linters (pyling, black, pep8). How could I change this behavior?

Comment: Flake8 doesn't do auto-formatting. If you ran it from a terminal on your second example, then you'd find it doesn't mind (or perhaps complains about indentation being the same as the function block). This is almost certainly a vscode problem and looks like you've black enabled in vscode

Comment: @IanStapletonCordasco indeed, I had black enabled! Sorry for the incomplete question